# MOCKITO - Change the exception thrown based on number of times the method is called

Tags: java, mockito, stub

I want to throw a specific exception for the first 5 times the method is executed. Afterwards, I want to throw another exception.

Ideally, I have this code snippet, which obviously doesn't work

```
int count = 0;
int max = 5;

@Test
public void myTest(){
   ...
   doThrow(count++ < max ? myException1 : myException2).when(myClass).myMethod()
   ...
}
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`thenThrow(Throwable... throwables)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenThrow(java.lang.Throwable...)) method on the [`OngoingStubbing`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html) instance returned by `Mockito.when(...)`.
The method accepts a `var-args` that are the exceptions to throw consecutively when the mocked method is invoked.

```
@Test
public void myTest(){
   // ...
   Mockito.when(myClass.myMethod())
          .thenThrow( myException1, 
                      myException1, 
                      myException1, 
                      myException1, 
                      myException1,
                      myException2);
   // ...
}
```

or by chaining `OngoingStubbing.thenThrow()` invocations as the method actually returns a `OngoingStubbing` object :

```
@Test
public void myTest(){
   // ...
   Mockito.when(myClass.myMethod())
          .thenThrow(myException1)
          .thenThrow(myException1)
          .thenThrow(myException1)
          .thenThrow(myException1)
          .thenThrow(myException1)
          .thenThrow(myException2);
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Where I'd insert the condition when alternating between myException1 and myException2?

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much

Comment: @raullalves You are welcome :) It doesn't produce a very beautiful code. Maybe instantiating an array would be better.

Comment: @davidxxx you can chain the `thenThrow` required number of times to make it look nicer e.g. `Mockito.when(...).thenThrow(...).thenThrow(...);`

Comment: @kdowbecki  Thanks for the information. I edited with as alternative. But I would prefer an equivalent to `Mockito.times()` . Something as `Mockito.when(myClass.myMethod()).thenThrow(myException1).times(5).thenThrow(myException2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can return exception at first call and another thing at second call:

```
when(myMock.myMethod(any()))
.thenThrow(new MyFirstException())
.thenThrow(new MySecondException())
.thenReturn(new MyObject();
```

This approach is useful in testing recursively called methods.

In the end I suggest checking if the method was called with the correct amount of times.

```
verify(myMock, times(3)).myMethod(any());
```